# Instantiating a derived class from Page throws CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE with C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I want to create my own derived class, `MyPage` from `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page`. I am using the XAML hosting API, and I have set my XAML source's `Content()` property to a `Frame` I created. To make my page class, I followed these steps:

1) Make IDL definition

```
namespace UI
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MyPage();
    }
}
```

2) I build the project, copy the generated header and source file from `project_root_folder\Debug\Generated Files\sources` to the project's root. I then add the files using the solution explorer.

3) I delete the `static_assert` from each of the files.

4) I build the project and instantiate my class as `winrt::UI::MyPage mypage;`.

The code compiles, but when the code execution reaches the line `winrt::UI::MyPage mypage;`, and `ClassFactory cannot supply the requested class` is thrown.

Comment: Did you remember to run cppwinrt with the -optimize flag? If you omit the flag, then you need to register the class in your manifest.

Comment: @Raymond Chen I turned on optimizations, added `#include "UI.MyPage.g.cpp"` to my source file, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @RaymondChen So I have created the class successfully. Now I'm trying to navigate to the page using `ContentFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<winrt::UI::MyPage>());` but I get a null pointer access violation. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated question.